# Nuxt js ssr: во view sorce вместо информации пришедшей с сервера отображается [object Object]

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Недавно работаю с ssr и возникла проблема, что рендер на сервере происходит не до конца. Если взглянуть во view sorce, то вместо информации пришедшей с сервера отображается не строками, как должно быть, а как [object Object]

так выглядит страница во view source

---

[image: во view sorce вместо информации пришедшей с сервера отображается [object Object]]

---

так она выглядит в браузере, после полной загрузки страницы

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: _«как исправить эту проблему?»_ - выводить объекты не через стандартное преобразование в строку, а каким-то другим способом (способ выбирать исходя из условий задачи).

Comment: @yar85 проблема в том, что это строка а не объект
<div>{{ valueData }}</div>
при загрузки страницы на мгновение тоже отображается как [object Object], а через секунду становится строкой которая лежит в переменной valueData

Comment: Строка - конечно не объект, в JS это примитивный тип. Когда ты преобразуешь объекты в строки, получается строковое значение `'[object Object]'` - оно и выводится.

Comment: @yar85 кажется вы меня не правильно поняли, я обновил описание.

Comment: Единственное чего я не понимаю в данной ситуации - так это попытку "переобуть" вoпрос о генерации разметки в вoпрос о том что отображается после отработки клиентских скриптов. Причина вывода `[object Object]` названа выше (дважды)... и если хочешь с ней поспорить, то спорь со [спецификацией ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-type-conversion), а не со мной. Вообще, о причине я написал по той причине что вoпрос не предполагает полезных ответов (собственно, поэтому ответов не дается)... и если тебе не хочется решать проблему, то имеешь полное право игнорировать написанное.